# is the vuforia SDK support the 3d tracking

Tags: augmented-reality, vuforia

I am a student and I am making my major project is about augmented reality and I have a good background in programming and my plan to make a very huge project in augmented reality
I have download the vuforia  SDK and I have make some samples using unity

**my question is the  vuforia  SDK support the 3d tracking 
I have seen the "Sesame Street Augmented Reality Dolls" in YouTube but I couldn't find under  which Section it has made**

Please inform me how to start doing this

This is the Visit http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U2jSzmvm_WA/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the moderators on the Vuforia forum:

> You cannot detect arbitrary 3D objects, but you can detect 3D objects
>   made up of planar image targets (e.g. a cereal box). Look for the
>   MultiImageTargets section of the Developer Guide and the AR Extension
>   for Unity 3 documentation
>   (https://ar.qualcomm.com/qdevnet/sdk/unity/ar). You can create
>   simple cube objects using the My Trackables system, or you can edit
>   the config.xml file by hand to arrange image targets into the desired
>   configuration.

A recent update allows Vuforia to [track 3D cylinder targets](https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/sample-apps/cylinder-targets).

The Sesame Street example was experimental and research is ongoing. There are no official plans to release it as a standard component of Vuforia yet.

Answer (score 0):

3D object tracking has now been officially added to the Vuforia 4.0 SDK:

https://developer.vuforia.com/library/articles/training/object-recognition

Note that it only works with small objects and the objects must be scanned using an Android app.